# adding a new theme in magento2

Tags: magento, themes, frontend, magento2, magento2.2

i have uploaded the files of the new theme bought from https://themeforest.net/user/codazon . But don't know where to move each individual files to the correct directories in order to add this new theme. Below is the files inside the new theme folder [image]
Below are the screenshot of what's inside the Theme zip file.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: kevin, i think that your purchased theme is complete magento installation else there would not be folders like 'vendor' and 'update' inside the theme folder.

Comment: you just need to copy complete folder in the root directory and then install magento

Comment: @SunilVerma, Hi i have added the screenshots of what's inside the them zip file. I tried to overwrite all the files, when i login to the backend it crashed. Should i just overwrite some folders only?

Comment: Hi Kevin, in case you still facing this problem, you need to delete all files you have currently in the root including DB, maybe after taking backup and then extract the zip file provided by the theme and do the installation again.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess which theme you have purchase but they must be providing a detailed documentation of that theme through http or wrap inside theme package. For example i have found http://www.codazon.com/document/fastest/magento2/ is the documentation for their M2 Fastest theme from [envatomarket](https://themeforest.net/item/fastest-magento-2-themes-magento-212-magento-19-multipurpose-responsive-theme-10-design/16178989?s_rank=4) page.

Answer (score 0):

Codazon has to kind of zip files one is with complete Magento package and the other has only extension and it’s documentation. Please find out it’s extension zip file only .